# Why is there a shift between the WWN reported from the controller and the Linux system?

Tags: hard-drive, zfs

I am in the process of setting up a ZFS storage system with a large number of disks. I want to use WWN numbers to identify devices (aliased in vdev_id.conf) but when trying to get the WWN numbers, I noted a shift between the WWN reported by the LSI controller (LSI MegaRAID SAS 9380-8e, all disks are in JBOD mode) and the WWN shown in /dev/disk/by-id:

```
$ storcli64 /c0/e72/s0 show all | grep 5008472696
WWN = 5000C5008472696C
0 Active 6.0Gb/s   0x5000c5008472696d 
1 Active 6.0Gb/s   0x5000c5008472696e 

$ ll /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x* | grep 5008472696
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5008472696f -> ../../sdn
```

On this set of hardware (Disks, JBOD, controller), the pattern seems to be consistent (shifted by 3).

I have a 'feeling' that this is caused by the dual link but I could not find a suitable explanation for this behavior. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Another sample would be

```
WWN = 5000C50084726B78
0 Active 6.0Gb/s   0x5000c50084726b79 
1 Active 6.0Gb/s   0x5000c50084726b7a
```

The controller reports `0x5000c50084726b7b`, which is consistent with the suggested explanation given by Matthew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a transport address and individual port identifiers for the dual-port SAS drives you're using (multipath). One WWN, multiple port identifiers.

A better illustration would be examining the output of:

`multipath -l`, `lsscsi --wwn` and `lsscsi --transport`

Like:

```
# lsscsi --transport
[0:0:0:0]    disk    sas:0x5000c50023601236          /dev/sdb
[0:0:1:0]    disk    sas:0x5000c50023614aee          /dev/sdc
[0:0:2:0]    disk    sas:0x5000c5007772e5fe          /dev/sdd
[0:0:4:0]    disk    sas:0x5000c5002362f346          /dev/sdf

# lsscsi --wwn
[0:0:0:0]    disk                                    /dev/sdb
[0:0:1:0]    disk    0x5000c50023614aef              /dev/sdc
[0:0:2:0]    disk                                    /dev/sdd
[0:0:4:0]    disk    0x5000c5002362f347              /dev/sdf

# multipath -ll | grep 3500
35000c50023614aef dm-6 HP      ,EF0450FARMV
35000c5002362f347 dm-3 HP      ,EF0450FARMV
```

For your purposes, go with the WWN. If this is ZFS, please elaborate on your controller and JBOD solution. If it's Linux, you should be using the DM Multipath and building the pool with the DM devices. Also see: https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the additional information provided in your zfs-ha setup. I checked the lsscsi and multipath outputs. Oddly, the `lsscsi --transport` does not show any WWN, the multipath WWN is consistent with that found in `by_id`. I'd be happy to elaborate on my intended ZFS setup, but I'm not sure this is the right channel. Will think of something.

Answer (score 1):

To round out the other answers, every SAS drive has a single LUN (LUN 0) and four addresses:

- the baseline target address, evenly-divisible by four, which is usually printed on the drive label as the WWN (e.g. `0x5000c5008472696c`)
- baseline+1: the address of the first port (e.g. `0x5000c5008472696d`)
- baseline+2: the address of the second port (e.g. `0x5000c5008472696e`)
- baseline+3: the LUN 0 address (e.g. `0x5000c5008472696f`)

Although all four addresses refer to the same drive, the LUN 0 address is what Linux presents as the WWN. It's the most portable, and—as ewwhite says— it's what you should use for ZFS.

(h/t to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/71s1jk/sg_ses_sas_address_is_off_by_one_for_every_disk/dnd5drs/) comment on r/zfs, which helped me wrap my head around it)

Answer (score 0):

This is purely an observation of just one of your entries but

```
0x5000c5008472696d  & 0x5000c5008472696e = 0x5000c5008472696c
0x5000c5008472696d  | 0x5000c5008472696e = 0x5000c5008472696f
```

It could be a difference in bitwise operations on how each system calculates the WWN.

Do you have any other examples?

If this is right (and I'm only guessing) I can only assume that no standard way exists and both the raid controller and the kernel implementations each choose a different method.

Comment: Nice catch on the bitwise operations. Not yet sure where to go from here since I was under the impression that the WWN is a device specific feature independent of the SAS addresses cause after all, it is printed on the disk sometimes. I guess I need to verify the WWNs are 'different but stable'. You helped a lot. Thanks.